# Electron together with live mode in Angular isn't loading node_module resources

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, angular-cli, vmware-clarity

## Context

I'm writing an application with Electron and Angular 2+ using Angular CLI. I've set up my electron .js file to point to the URL provided by the `ng serve` command, that usually is `localhost:4200`, in order to capture the code changes. Some considerations:

- The address `localhost:4200` points to `index.html`;
- `index.js` is my Electron entry point script

Here is my `index.js` file used as an entry point for the electron module.

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

let win = null;

function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 1000, height: 600, show: false});
  win.loadURL('http://localhost:4200');

  win.maximize();
  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null;
  });
  win.on('ready-to-show', () => {
    win.show();
  });
  win.webContents.openDevTools();
}

app.on('ready', () => {
  createWindow();
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

And my `index.html` file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BRISA Carbon</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <!--Clarity Design Elements-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/clarity-icons/clarity-icons.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/clarity-icons/clarity-icons.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

## My Problem

When I run `ng serve`, the node_modules resources inside the .html file are not being loaded and the Chrome console outputs the following messages

[image]

I know that the path to the resources are correct because I'm using WebStorm IDE and I can go to the referenced element through a link like this image below.

[image]

Why my resources are not being loaded when I'm running in Angular live mode?

Comment: Can you provide the whole path to the path to the files that fails to load (from Network tab)?

Comment: Make sure you review both the Angular docs https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-lib and Clarity docs https://vmware.github.io/clarity/get-started on how to include library assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everyone that is having this same problem, I just found a solution. Instead of loading my resources through the `index.html` file, I've placed them in the `.angular-cli.json`. Basically, Angular 2+ has the own way of importing resources and seems that is not correct loading resources from the main .html file.

Well, for scripts (I mean, .js files), I'm placing it in the `scripts` array and styles inside the `styles` array. The `.angular-cli.json` file section that I've changed looks like this:

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/clarity-icons/clarity-icons.min.css",
    "../node_modules/clarity-ui/clarity-ui.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min.js",
    "../node_modules/clarity-icons/clarity-icons.min.js"
  ]
```

Hope that this information will help someone else. For me everything is working just fine.

Comment: Adding stylesheets and scripts to the `.angular-cli.json` file is the correct way to add external dependencies to your angular-cli app.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're experiencing the same problem when you're visiting `localhost:4200` in your browser also?

In your index.html you're referencing to `../node_modules/ ...` which works in your IDE because that's how the folder structure looks like.

Let's say your folder structure looks like this:

```
node_modules/
src/
```

And `src` is the folder that your server's using as root. Then the server wont be able to retrieve files from `..` (since a root dir has no parent dir).

Instead of referencing to the JS files in your index.html, you should import/require them in your other JS files. Exactly how you do that depnds on your building/bundling tools (eg Webpack and/or Babel).

```
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min.js'
import 'clarity-icons/clarity-icons.min.js'
import 'clarity-icons/clarity-icons.min.css' // Assumes that you use webpack and webpack-css-loader, for example
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @kontrollanten. However, I've not tested your solution because I'm not working with Webpack since Angular CLI has its own build process. By the way I've found a solution. See my answer.

Comment: Angular CLI uses Webpack also, so it should work just fine :) I prefer this solution, to keep all the code dependencies in one place. I'm glad you solved your problem.